# SePolicy for Vendor to access device binder

Tags: android, selinux

The problem that i face is I have a vendor domain which is accessing hwservice manager, and when i compile for user build i get the following denial.

```
11-11 11:13:28.126  5228  5228 W vps     : type=1400 audit(0.0:248): avc: denied { read write } for name="binder" dev="tmpfs" ino=11419 scontext=u:r:vpsd:s0 tcontext=u:object_r:binder_device:s0 tclass=chr_file permissive=0
```

After running audit2allow tool i get the suggestion to add policy like below.

```
allow vpsd binder_device:chr_file { ioctl open read write };
```

But as per the treble architecture its not allowed and build fails.

Error as below :

```
Compilation error.
neverallow check failed at out/target/product/titan_r1_base/obj/ETC/nonplat_sepolicy.cil_intermediates/nonplat_sepolicy.cil:2633
  (neverallow base_typeattr_38_26_0 binder_device_26_0 (chr_file (ioctl read write getattr lock append open)))
    <root>
    allow at out/target/product/titan_r1_base/obj/ETC/nonplat_sepolicy.cil_intermediates/nonplat_sepolicy.cil:5998
      (allow vpsd binder_device_26_0 (chr_file (read write)))
```

Can someone please advise me what to add policy for the above .

I have tried

```
allow vpsd hwbinder_device:chr_file { ioctl open read write };
```

and

```
allow vpsd vndbinder_device:chr_file { ioctl open read write };
```

Please suggest.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The new treble architecture aims to decouple vendor component's dependency on the framework. This in turn will allow to upgrade the framework without involving the vendor in the process (see [Treble](https://source.android.com/devices/architecture/treble)).

To achieve this, vendor components are restricted access to the framework binder, and should only use the vndbinder (vendor binder) to interact with other vendor components. Essentially, vendor components are expected not to interact directly with the framework.

On treble versions (8.0 +), the SE-Policy enforces this concept by defining 'coredomain' neverallow rules. Basically, most of the internal framework components and processes are associated with the coredomain attribute, while new vendor defined components are not associated with the coredomain attribute.
This means, that when you define a new type in your vendor SE-policy, this type will not be a coredomain, and will be restricted by neverallow rules.

> Framework processes described in this section correspond to coredomain in sepolicies while vendor processes correspond to non-coredomain. For example, /dev/binder can be accessed only in coredomain and /dev/vndbinder can be accessed only in non-coredomain.

(Source: [AOSP official documentation](https://source.android.com/devices/architecture/vndk/dir-rules-sepolicy)).

Concreatly, under the public [domain.te](http://androidxref.com/8.0.0_r4/xref/system/sepolicy/public/domain.te#512) file, you can see the neverallow rule that defines that only coredomain + appdomain can read/write the binder_device:

> #On full TREBLE devices, only core components and apps can use Binder and servicemanager. Non-core domain apps need this because Android framework offers many of its services to apps as Binder services.
>
> full_treble_only(`   neverallow {
>       domain
>       -coredomain
>       -appdomain
>       -binder_in_vendor_violators # TODO(b/35870313): Remove once all violations are gone   } binder_device:chr_file rw_file_perms;

Comment: allow vpsd hwbinder_device:chr_file rw_file_perms;